# Examples of uncountable subgroups, but with countably many cosets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My question is pretty much as stated in the title: what examples are there (or does there exist) uncountable subgroups of a group but which have countably-infinite many cosets.  I can only think of examples in the other direction (countable subgroups giving uncountably-many cosets).

Comment: Your question seems to be ill-posed: for cosets you need a subgroup, so perhaps you want an uncountable group with an uncountable subgroup of infinite-countable index?

Comment: @DonAntonio Isn't that what OP explicitly asked for?

Comment: I don't think so, @anon, unless you can make sense of "[groups]...giving infinitely-countable many cosets" . As far as I kno,w, a group "doesn't give cosets", and there's *always* a subgroup involved.

Comment: OP says "uncountable *subgroups* which give [i.e. yield or have] [countably-infinitely] many cosets."

Comment: The question is *all* the words in it, not only part of them.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're talking about. OP uses the word "subgroup" multiple times; the only time the word "group" itself is used is in the tag (group-theory).

Comment: @Don Is it well posed now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The uncountable subgroup of $\Bbb Z^{[0,1]}$ of maps $[0,1]\to\Bbb Z$ vanishing at $0$ has index $|\Bbb Z|=\aleph_0$.

Answer (score 3):

How about $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}$? Or take any countably infinite group $H$, uncountable group $K$ and consider $K$ in  $H \times K$.

Answer (score 3):

You can take the group $SO(n)$ inside $O(n)$. It has only two cosets!